# Array issue in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting

I have an university project in C programming. I ran into a problem with the following task. My program should order numbers in two arrays. In the first array i must save (the biggest of every fifth element) and that is my problem. I am not sure how to make the loop which reads five elements compare them, take the biggest one, and then continue doing this with the other elements. I am hoping someone to help because I blocked.

```
#define A 100

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


void show(int x[], int nx); //функция за показване на масивите
float vavedi(int x[], int nx); //функция, чрез която ръчно въвеждаме числата и ги обработваме
FILE* readFile(char* fname); //функция която чете файл и представя съдържанието му като масиви

int main()
{
    int call, a = 0, b = 0, mode = 0, i = 0;
    int check = 0;
    char fail[A];
    char* menu[] = {
     "PROGRAM STARTED!",
     "Enter an option:",
     "1 : Write the numbers.",
     "2 : Choose from a file.",
     "0 : Exit."
    };

    do {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s\n", menu[i]);

        check=scanf("%d", &mode);

            if (check != 1)
                printf("ERROR! Try again!");


        switch (mode)
        {
            case 1: {
                //в случай 1 числата се въведждат от потребителя
                call = vavedi(a, b);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                //в случай 2 потребителя използва съществуващ файл
                printf("Enter the path of the file you want to open:\n");
                scanf("%s", fail);
                call = readFile(fail);
                if (call == NULL) {
                    printf("The file doesn't exist! Try again!\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case 0:
                break;

            default:
            {
                printf("ERROR! Try again!\n");
            }
        }

    } while (mode != 0);

    printf("\nThe program ended!\n");
    return 0;
}
void show(int x[], int nx)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < nx; k++)
        {
         printf("\n Element[%d]= %d", k, x[k]);
        }
}

float vavedi(int x[], int nx)
{
    int call=0;
    int enter=0;
    int imin, max;
    int b[A], c[A];
    int i, j, j1, count;
    j = 0;
    do {
        printf("\nCount of the elements:");
        scanf("%d", &count);
            if (count <= 0 || count > 100)
                printf("Invalid input! Try again!\n");
    } while (count <= 0 || count > 100);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter an element:");
        scanf("%d", &c[i]);
    } 


    printf("\n");
    return enter;
}
```

Comment: `i` never changes in your second loop...

Comment: `max5(a, b, c, d, e)` can be implemented as `max(a, max(b, max(c, max(d, e))))` (where `max` is your textbook function (or macro) that returns the greatest of two values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : Including header file mentioned by @pmg.

If i understand correctly, your problem is to find largest element for every five elements:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <limits.h> // Put this after your header files
    ..
    .. //Rest of the code.
    ..
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       printf("\nEnter an element:");
       scanf("%d", &c[i]);
    } 

   size_t size = ceil(count/5.0);
   memset(b , INT_MIN , size);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
   {
      b[i/5] = b[i/5] > c[i] ? b[i/5] : c[i];
   }

   // Print b like this:
   for(i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
       printf("%d" , b[i] );
```

Let's see how this works for array of size `9`. array's indices will go from `0 to 8` . If I divide each of them by 5, I get `0` for `i = 0 to 4` and `1` for `i = 5 to 8`. Now we can take max over elements in buckets of 5. You seem to be a beginner, hope this helps you in creating better understanding.

Comment: I ca'g get what is INT_MAX and how to use it?

Comment: `INT_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`

Comment: @ЦветомирБановски Please check now.

Comment: I have a problem with the max now

Comment: @ЦветомирБановски Please specify what your problem is.

Comment: That is the most difficult part. Is there any chance if I send you the whole code and you tell me how to to this?

Comment: Update the post itself. If i could, I would help you out.

Comment: I updated the post and uploaded the whole code. I wil be grateful if someone helps me :)

Comment: Give an example of what array `c` will have and what array `b` should have. Again, in post.

Comment: Array c should store all the elements which were entered, Array b should store the biggest of each five numbers.

Comment: @ЦветомирБановски Give example using numbers like if `c` has `[ 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 , 5, 6 ,7 ,8,9 ]`. What should `b` have?

Comment: b should have 5, because it is the biggest number among [1-5]. Then b should have 9, because it is the biggest of the group [6-9]. If the array contained different numbers e.g. c=[ 33, 4, 18, 6 , 23, 1, 9, 78, 11, 24], then b=[33, 78]

Comment: @ЦветомирБановски Updated my answer. Please accept if you think it's correct.

Comment: But again, it gives error on the line where `b[i/5] = max(b[i/5] , c[i]);` It sais that 'max' is not a function

Comment: You could define `max` function or use my updated answer.

Comment: @E.N.D Excuse me, but do you have an opportunity to look for another thing, related to the code you gave me. It works when I input the numbers manually, but when I use a text file instead, than contains random integers, it doesn't calculate them properly. If I upload my code, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @ЦветомирБановски Simply ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The other problem is the following:

```
{

   int c[A], b[A];
   int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, num;
   FILE* fp= NULL; //указател за файл
   fp = fopen(fname, "r");
   if (fp)
   {
       while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &c[i]) != EOF)
       i++;

      num=i;
    size_t size = ceil(num/5.0);
    memset(b , INT_MIN , size);
    for(i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)
   {
     b[i/5] = b[i/5] > c[i] ? b[i/5] : c[i];
   }
   printf("\nARRAY1:\n");
   for(i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
   {
    buble(b, i);
    printf(" Element[%d]=%1d\n", i, b[i]);
   }

   printf("\nARRAY2:");
   buble(c, num);
   show(c, num);

   printf("\n");

   }
  fclose(fp);
return fp;
}

It doesn't calculate the rigth way.
```

Comment: @E.N.D what do you think?